# Windows sc.exe command: Access is Denied when querying service on a remote machine

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, servicecontroller

I am trying to query a service on a remote machine using the windows sc command but keep getting the following error `[sc] enumqueryservicesstatus openservice failed 5 Access is denied`, any body have an idea what exactly i need to change on the remote machine for this to work? User permission? Every user on my remote machine is an administrator. Perhaps some firewall blocking? Or some service not running?

I am running the following command which queries the RemoteRegistry service:

```
sc \\<remote machine ip address> query RemoteRegistry
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running the command from an elevated DOS prompt?

Comment: Is this a Domain environment or Workstation environment? Either way like @CoreTech said, you would have to run command prompt as Admin if UAC is enabled.

Comment: @CoreTech Yes its running in admin mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned off windows UAC on the remote machine, it fixed it.